# Using old RAM sticks

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have been looking on what to do with several (as in 25+) sticks of RAM, all of which are generally old and small in memory size. I was hoping to find a way to use several or all on a single motherboard (with obvious modifications and/or a separate system for it), but, alas, I have yet to find any mentionable method. I am determined to find a use for these though, and so I am here, asking this question:

Is there a way to combine several different RAM sticks into a system that has one output that would connect to the motherboard in one of the RAM slots? Is there a way to do this without causing the better RAM sticks to be limited by the limitations of the lesser of the RAM sticks?

Comment: They make good keychains

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, you cannot use old memory modules in new systems. If you still have an old system that will take it, great! But otherwise...

You can be crafty and make [keychains](http://www.geekware.ca/bmz_cache/3/326de4da1cbd2596c90d99ca6d8eb8c5.image.400x400.jpg), [earrings](http://cdn6.gadgetvenue.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/RAM-Earrings.jpg), etc. If you are into creating cool models, you can try building a mini house or something. And finally, if you have access to a smelter, you could melt it down for its precious metals.

As for actual use in a computer? Without a motherboard that supports it, you won't be using it.

Comment: Additional, arguably more practical use: sell it on eBay (if it's something people would buy), or donate it to a school that has old computers.

Comment: In addition to this, anything that would be able to support multiple sticks, seemingly of varying sizes and speeds, would likely cost more than quadruple what it would be to buy two 8GB sticks of DDR3. So even if there was some way to get all of those random pieces of RAM to run in unison, the power usage, efficiency and cost would likely all be inferior to just buying a couple sticks of new RAM. Even if they were all 512mb sticks, together they'd only make up 12.8GB or so.