# Using a new memory ram and almost a broken memory ram together

Tags: memory, memtest

I just bought a new memory ram(TwinMOS,2GB,DDR3,1333 MHz),I tested it using memtest and it passed the test without any error

but I have another memory ram (GEIL, 2GB,DDR3, 1333MHz) which I used it for 2 years and is kind of broken,I tested it using memtest and it contain a lot of errors but the thing is it also work standalone(but sometimes I get bluescreen in windows and I can not install any linux distro )

now the question is Can I use both of them on the same PC ? I'm afraid if I use them together,old memory broke new memory too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the defective memory will not damage your new memory.

But more importantly, why use your defective memory at all?  It is with almost 100% certainty that it is causing your blue screens and your inability to install other OSs.

**Throw the bad memory in to the trash.**

Comment: I'd suggest [recycling](http://www.recycleyourelectronics.ca/) before trashing, but I agree completely otherwise. ;)

Comment: And even if it won’t cause the operating system to crash, it _will_ introduce subtle file corruption that will be detected too late.

Comment: reasonable answer,I thought if I use defective memory with a healthy memory it will not causing any blue screen,but from your answer I think I was wrong,thank you

Comment: Just think of it as RAID 0 of sorts. No redundancy there.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 http://superuser.com/questions/603286/using-old-ram-sticks/603298#603298 also has a few ideas